# Duplicate Symbol linker error

Tags: ios, json, linker-errors

I have an existing app in which I added the json-framework.  Now it won't compile due to a duplicate symbol linker error.

The error seems to be due to the installed Millenial Media ad network SDK which also links to the json-framework.  It seems the json-framework must be already embedded in MMs .a static library file.  If I dont add the SDK then I cant import the json-framework for use in my own code, but when I do the compiler raises this exception.

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SBJsonParser.maxDepth in /users/laptop/Developer/sandbox/testapp_sources_add_owntracking/testapp/AdNetworkLibs/MillenialMedia/libMMSDK.a(SBJsonParser.o) and /Users/laptop/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-bjxtaanqoewrondmjnucarxebkka/Build/Intermediates/testapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testapp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonParser.o for architecture i386
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the json framework header files without adding the json class implementation files.  If these classes are in another library, then they will be linked with that library.

Comment: Champion answer!  I removed the .m implementation files and kept the .h header files.  It now compiles and my code can access the json classes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your project, you have **SBJsonParsor** added twice.

This might have happend as some of the  library (source) you are using (added to project) already have **SBJsonParsor** added without your active knowledge about the same.

You need to check your project hierarchy and remove one of the reference.

Comment: If I remove the json-framework classes which I added then I am not able to access those classes.  That is because the first instance of those classes seem to be included in the Millenial Media '.a' file.
My question is how can I use the json-framework classes in my code.  Can I access the classes already within the .a file, or how can I add these classes again so I can use them?